# Magento 2 - create custom script on root directory

Tags: magento2, script

In Magento 1.9 I simply use below code and Magento's `Mage` model could be run on the script then

```
include_once 'App.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/../app/Mage.php';
```

How can I do it in Magento 2? So that I would be able to create custom script on root directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this way..

```
<?php  
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include(__DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php');

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
```

Comment: Getting 404 not found error. https://www.screencast.com/t/fU8IM0X4

Comment: @MuhammadAnas problem in file permission above code is working code

Comment: getting this error `PHP Warning:  include(app/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: still getting error `PHP Warning: include(app/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: I don't know who gave negative on your answer. Is your answer is correct?

Comment: I have used this code `include(__DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php');` and your script is working not. +1 for your effort.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


**********add your code******************
```

Comment: Rakesh Donga's answer is working fine. +1 for your effort though.